# Is there a good reason to put the company name at the beginning of the table names?

Tags: database-design, naming-convention

When developing a new system, for a big corporation.

Technologies:
Web, Java, Spring Boot, Rest Api, Postgres, Hibernate

Company:
Bank

System:
Promissory control, and all others

Company name:
Mycorp

Systems:
Many systems, dozens, dozens...

Is there a good reason to put the company name at the beginning of the table names?

For example, for the users table: `mycorp_users`

Sometimes I see something like this, the company name + the system name + ...: `mycorp_systemx_users`

Why not use a schema for this? `dbmycorp.systemx.users`

Or even not use anything only: `someschema.users`

Comment: But this is independent of environment, no matter what the requirements, this is a common practice in almost all consultancies.

Comment: The company is a Bank, The system is a promissory system, All systems here, all databases use this convention.

Comment: Are there multiple mycorp per database? Or is it literally just one name repeated everywhere?

Comment: @YannickLiekens, only one name repeated everywhere.

Comment: @JamesKenkins, I improved my question.

Comment: Do you work for the bank, or do you work for different company who is building the system for the bank?

Comment: "*Is there a good reason to put the company name at the beginning of the table names*" - I can't think of any reason why this would be a good idea.

Comment: @JamesJenkins, I work for a different company, yes, that is building the system for the bank

Comment: Related: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251/is-adding-the-tbl-prefix-to-table-names-really-a-problem

Comment: @JamesJenkins, here in my country, this practice is ubiquitous in all companies, no matter the area or who creates the systems, or who takes care of the databases

Comment: I like a lot some answers about schemas: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/8919/143247, https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/8518/143247

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naming conventions are usually there for a reason.

Perhaps a good idea is to ask the people in charge why this naming convention was chosen this way. Since you work in bank these naming conventions are (in general) pretty strict, and perhaps useful in the bigger picture.

But from what I can read in your comments and in your post, then no, I don't see much use in using the naming convention you specified.

I would also much rather use schemas as you've said yourself. This gives you the added benefit of being able to specify permissions on the separate schemas.

Answer (score 2):

As you say in the comments

> I work for a different company, yes, that is building the system for the bank

I suspect this is a requirement of the company you work for and/or the expectations of the purchasing bank.

When the build is complete `mycorp` is going to be all over in the code.  If you wanted to sell the same product to `DifferentCorp` it would be a lot of work to remove reference to `mycorp`.  I assume that by adding `mycorp` they bank paying you to custom build a product for them, will have some feeling that you will not be going and selling to their competition, as soon as you get it working.

See related

- [Is adding the ‘tbl’ prefix to table names really a problem?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/154251/21924)
- [What are some best practices for using schemas in SQL Server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/4075/21924)

Comment: The "best practices for SQL Server" might not be relevant for PostgreSQL (which is what danilo is using)

Comment: "a lot of work" really reduces to a global search-and-replace, with a recompile.